# Creating a new column of local times from correct UTC times

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pytz

times = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Time':['2020-03-14 12:00:00']*5,
     'TimeZone':['US/Pacific','US/Arizona','US/Mountain',
                 'US/Central','US/Eastern']})
times.Time = times.Time.map(
    lambda x: datetime.fromisoformat(x).astimezone(pytz.utc))
times.TimeZone = times.TimeZone.map(pytz.timezone)
```

I want to do two things with this script.

1. Before any further operations, I want `times.Time` to all be 12:00 noon in UTC instead of mapping forward/backward based on my local time zone. Ideally I want this script to run the same anywhere in the world without having to manually account for the machine's local time zone.
2. I want to create a third column of `datetime` objects that are the same time as `times.Time` but in `times.TimeZone` time zones.

How can I do this?

Comment: It would help if you could paste your expected output as a table. It will be easier to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1, you should use `pd.to_datetime` followed by `tz_localize`. For #2, it's a `tz_convert`:

```
times['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(times['Time']).dt.tz_localize('utc')
times['TimeZone'] = times['TimeZone'].map(pytz.timezone)

# This operation is not vectorized (read: slow)
times['LocalTime'] = times.apply(lambda row: row['Time'].tz_convert(row['TimeZone']), axis=1)
```

Result:

```
                       Time     TimeZone                  LocalTime
0 2020-03-14 12:00:00+00:00   US/Pacific  2020-03-14 05:00:00-07:00
1 2020-03-14 12:00:00+00:00   US/Arizona  2020-03-14 05:00:00-07:00
2 2020-03-14 12:00:00+00:00  US/Mountain  2020-03-14 06:00:00-06:00
3 2020-03-14 12:00:00+00:00   US/Central  2020-03-14 07:00:00-05:00
4 2020-03-14 12:00:00+00:00   US/Eastern  2020-03-14 08:00:00-04:00
```